# Incorrect Syntax near 'Name' and also give warning at cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

```
private void btsSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        string sql = "insert into tblRegistration (Name,Father Name) Values( '" + txtName.Text + "', '" + txtFname.Text + "' )";

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con);

        if (cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() != null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Data Saved");

            txtName.Text = "";
            txtFname.Text = "";
            txtName.Focus();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: What are the mame of the tablet fields?

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection - check out [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/)

Comment: And once you've parameterized the values, you'll need to escape the table name to handle it having a space in it.

Answer (score 0):

It is generally a good idea to avoid spaces in column names. I don't think using single quotes around a column name with spaces is valid in SQL Server (if that's what you're using). Instead, you'll want to wrap the column name in square brackets, so:

```sql
insert into tblRegistration(Name, [Father Name])
...
```

I also recommend using parameterized queries to mitigate SQL injection risk: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters?view=netframework-4.8

Your query would look like this as well as setting parameters:

```c#
// Query text
string sql = "insert into tblRegistration (Name, [Father Name]) values (@Name, @FatherName)";

// After you create your cmd object
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", txtName.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FatherName", txtFname.Text);
```